# Proving countability and uncountability

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am given two sets:

$$A=  \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}^2 \mid x-y \in \mathbb{Z}  \}$$

$$B=  \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x-y \in \mathbb{Q}  \}$$

I am told that $A$ is countable and $B$ is not. For a set to be countable I need to show that the cardinality of that set is less than or the same as the one for the natural numbers. If this is not the case it is uncountable.

If I could find a injection from A into $\mathbb{N}$ I am done. If I can show that no injection exists from $B$ into $\mathbb{N}$ I am done. However, this method does not seem to be that obvious here.

I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is uncountable and $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable as well as $\mathbb{Z}$ but do not know how to proceed.

How do I formally show that $A$ is countable but $B$ is not (I am really interested in the method/approach)?

Comment: You can write down bijections $A \simeq \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Z$ and $B\simeq\mathbb R\times \mathbb Q$

Comment: $A$ is clearly infinite but also it is a subset of $\Bbb Q^2$, so it is forced to be countably infinite. $B$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, so $|B|\le\mathfrak{c}$, but also $B$ contains $\{(x,x):x\in\Bbb R\}\cong\Bbb R$ so $|B|\ge\mathfrak{c}$, so $|B|=\mathfrak{c}$. This saves you the potential effort of writing down explicit bijections

Comment: @SolubleFish I am unfamiliar with the notation. Could you expand on this approach?

Comment: @FShrike This makes complete sense but I am having trouble figuring out how you came about that set and the notation "$\cong$"

Comment: @learningsolo $\cong$ is extremely standard notation for ‘isomorphism’ or ‘is isomorphic to’. $\simeq$ is sometimes used for this purpose also but be careful, in different contexts it can mean a different thing (usually a weaker thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}^2$ itself is countable. Since $A\subset\mathbb{Q}^2$, It should also be countable.

We have the subset $H=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}\subset B$. $H$ is clearly uncountable since you have trivial bijection from $H$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This proves that $B$ is uncountable as well.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The first one makes complete sense to me. I am having a bit of trouble of seeing how you came up with $H$ and what the trivial bijection is. Side note: I think what is/was throwing me off was the $x-y\in\cdot$

Comment: @learningsolo $x\mapsto(x,x)$ is the bijection

Comment: @FShrike thank you for the clarifications. I will read up on isomorphisms. Is there a reason for $H$ being defined in that way (or in another way; how do I come up with H to form the bijection?).

Comment: @learningsolo We're just looking for an uncountable thing contained in $B$. $H$ is one of the easiest choices since it is most clearly a copy of $\Bbb R$

Comment: @FShrike the bijection is from $H\to\mathbb{R}^2$, no? no to $\mathbb{R}$ as the answer says or am I missunderstanding?

Comment: @learningsolo You are misunderstanding. Though it is also true that $H\cong\Bbb R^2$ as sets

Comment: @FShrike Then I am clearly still not getting it but I would really love to fully understand this. If $H\subset B$ and $H$ consists of pairs $(x,x)$ and the bijection is given by $x \mapsto (x,x)$ wouldn't that yield domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$? (or $H\to\mathbb{R}^2$)

Comment: @learningsolo $H$ is still a set. $\Bbb R\ni x\mapsto(x,x)\in H$ is a genuine function with domain $\Bbb R$ and codomain $H$. It is a bijection, too

Comment: @FShrike This was probably my confusion. Since it is a bijection it doesn't matter if we map $(x,x) \mapsto x$  with domain $H$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}$ or $x \mapsto (x,x)$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $H$. Since the subset $H$ of $B$ is uncountable since we have a bijection between the sets $H$ and $\mathbb{R}$ this means that $B$ must be uncountable.

Comment: @learningsolo That's right.